# How can I access post data in grouped into arrays

Tags: php, csv

I have an employee_id and a number that will get passed to me as a post request.

I want to be able to retrieve the ids like:

```
$employee_id = $_GET['employee_id'];
$number = $_GET['number'];
```

Then store these into something like as they come in:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => sddsfdsf
            [number] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => fdgfdgfdg
            [number] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => dfgfgfg
            [number] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => dfgfdgfdg
            [number] => 1
        )

)
```

So I can access these and read, compare and write to a csv file if the values exist or not or if they are of different values (0,1)

Whats the best way to first get these into an array as they come in?

Comment: What do you mean '... as they come in'? Is a form submitting data for multiple employees or a single employee? 
Create a parent array to store everyone, then create a sub-array for each employee and append it to the parent array.

Comment: You can't, unless you read the CSV in at the beginning. A PHP script is executed again with every single request, it's stateless so the data you hold in a local array will be reset. Unless you save it in a session or somewhere outside of the PHP script itself.

Comment: @waterloomatt yes will be like a form submitting data

Comment: @xander yes but as the data comes in it will read, compare and write to the csv

Comment: your form will have inputs or what .. if yes you can get this to work by setting the input name as `<input name="employee_id[]"` and then you have to iterate and construct your array .. Try to describe better your approach

Comment: Please link the format of your input data (from $_GET or $_POST)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define arrays very similar to how you would in PHP.  Just make sure the indexes match:

```
<input name="data[0][employee_id]" />
<input name="data[0][number]" />
<input name="data[1][employee_id]" />
<input name="data[1][number]" />
```

Then access `$_POST['data']` and read the values:

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $data) {
    echo $data['employee_id'];
    echo $data['number'];
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't I use GET like below to read the values that come in as a POST? Also thanks for the html but this will be coming through Angluar POST

Comment: Ummm... No. If you post a form the data will be in `$_POST` and `$_GET` will be empty.  This depends on the `<form method=""` value.

Comment: You show `$_GET` in your code but you mention _passed to me as a post request_ so use whichever one is your form `method`.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need input array multiple times, something like this:

```html
<input name="employee_id[]" />
<input name="employee_id[]" />
<input name="employee_id[]" />
```

Than when all of them are filled you can loop them in php and add them to array:

```
$employees = [];
foreach($_GET['employee_id'] as $key => $employee_id) {
  array_push($employees, [
    'employee_id' => $employee_id,
    'number' => $_GET['number'][$key]
  ]);
}
```

Comment: @Sam this sums up my comment.. try this out

Comment: Yes this is good thanks but how can I have them as a key value pair as the employee_id needs to be matched with the number that comes in?

Comment: If they have exactly same number you can call number array with key. Edited original answer.